# Join rows in a data frame which have similar (but not equal) values

Tags: r, data.table, fuzzyjoin

I have a `df` like:

```
   SampleID Chr Start End    Strand  Value
1:   rep1     1 11001 12000     -     10
2:   rep1     1 15000 20100     -     5
3:   rep2     1 11070 12050     -     1
4:   rep3     1 14950 20090     +     20
...
```

And I want to join the rows that share the same `chr` and `strand` and that have similar starting and end points (say like with 100 +/- distance). For those columns that the row join is performed, I would also like to concatenate the `SampleID` names and the `Value`. With the previous example, something like:

```
   SampleID Chr Start End    Strand  Value
1:rep1,rep2   1 11001 12000     -     10,1
2:   rep1     1 15000 20100     -     5
4:   rep3     1 14950 20090     +     20
...
```

Ideas? Thanks!

EDIT:

I found the fuzzyjoin package for R (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html). Does anyone have experience with this package?

EDIT2:

It would be also nice if just one of the variables (`SampleID` or `Value`) would be concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

We could do group by 'Chr', 'Strand', create a grouping ID based on the difference between adjacent elements in 'Start' and 'End' columns after `order`ing by 'Start', 'End', then grouped by 'Chr', 'Strand' and 'ind', get the first element of 'Start', 'End', while `paste`ing the elements in 'SampleID' and 'Value' column

```
library(data.table)
df[order(Start, End), ind := rleid((Start - shift(Start, fill = Start[1])) < 100 & 
     (End -  shift(End, fill = End[1])) < 100), by =.(Chr, Strand)
   ][, .(Start = Start[1], End = End[1], 
     SampleID = toString(SampleID), Value = toString(Value)) , .(Strand, Chr, ind),]
#     Strand Chr ind Start   End   SampleID Value
#1:      -   1   1 11001 12000 rep1, rep2 10, 1
#2:      -   1   2 15000 20100       rep1     5
#3:      +   1   1 14950 20090       rep3    20
```

NOTE: Assumed that 'df' is a `data.table`

Comment: WOW! That's great, I would like to know if you could be a little bit more explicit with the command that you just used. Correct me if I'm wrong:

You generate a "Label" for each condition looking at the `Chr`, `Strand` and the `Start` and `End` which fulfills the requirement that I asked (+/- 100). Then you joined the ones with the same "Label" and add the `SampleID` and `Value` as a string. Am I right?

Another curious thing that happens in my `data.table` is that the rows that are exactly at the same position do not perform the join. Where would be the problem?

Comment: @Tato14 In the first set of `df[i, j, by]`  we specify the `i` with `order` so that the values are ordered in the ascending order.  The `by` is the grouping variables 'Chr', 'Strand', In the 'j', we assign the run-length-id (`rleid`) of logical output as  a new columns, then in the second set, we are doing a group by operation.  It is not clear when u say that `rows that are exactly at the sam position do not perform the join`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Regarding the last part, by "position" I meant same `Chrom`, `Strand`, `Start` and `End`.

Comment: I also found in the output some rows with joined `SampleID`s that do not match the conditions about `Start` and `End` but get the same `id`. If I only run the first part of the command a warning message appear: `RHS 1 is length 344 (greater than the size (32) of group 1). The last 312 element(s) will be discarded. RHS 1 is length 344 (greater than the size (5) of group 2)...`